# SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 installation - placing .config files into the GAC

Tags: 2013, 2013-sp1

I have to install some additional files into the GAC as part of the SDL Tridion SP1 upgrade, I'm currently following the steps defined here (log on required):

http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-2C54E5AA-271A-4482-B14B-54060EDFD3A4

I notice that the steps are asking to install .config files into the c:/windows/assembly folder, but I cannot find a way to copy these (I registered the dlls using gacutil) and I always thought it was impossible to add .config files here.

Is this a mistake in the docs, or my mistake and there is a way to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do this.  On a 64 bit machine running .NET 4+ the GAC is actually here: c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly The path you're referring to is for 32 bit apps.

Try searching for your registered DLL in that folder and place your config in the same folder.

However, placing configs for a DLL in the GAC is not a good approach according to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311253/config-files-for-assemblies-in-gac.  The config should technically be part of the app that uses the DLL and would go in its BIN folder.